# Adding DataBound DropDownList to DataGrid

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, datagrid, drop-down-menu

I have a `DataGrid` bound to a `DataView` which, among other columns has, an ID Column and ParentID Column, I need the user to be able to specify a ParentID using using a `DropDownList` (ComboBox).

Now, I have already added the DropDownList to the DataGrid like this:

```
<Columns>
    [...]
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Parent" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlParentID" 
                              runat="server" 
                              DataValueField="ID"
                              DataTextField="Short_Description"
                              Width="100%"
                              DataSource="<%# dsDV %> ">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
</Columns>
```

In the code-behind I have the following a method:

```
Protected dsDV As New DataView
Protected Sub PopulateDropDownList()
    Dim conn As SqlClient.SqlConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(myConnString)
    Dim comm As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM myTable", conn)
    comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Dim myTableTable As New DataTable
    conn.Open()

    myTableTable.Load(comm.ExecuteReader)
    Me.dsDV = myTableTable.DefaultView
End Sub
```

That `PopulateDropDownMethod` is called on the form Load Event but, albeit DDLs do show, they show empty, as if no DataBinding is being made.

How can I properly bind the DDL with a dataSource in the codebehind? Or, if that's not the issue, how do I properly fill the DDL?

### Update 1

After the first answer I went ahead and tried this (still no luck):

```
Protected Sub dg_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles dgData.ItemDataBound
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
        Dim ddl As DropDownList = CType(e.Item.Cells(3).FindControl("ddlParentID"), DropDownList)
        Me.PopulateDropDownList(ddl)
    End If
End Sub

Protected dsDV As New DataView
Protected Sub PopulateDropDownList(ddl As DropDownList)
    Dim conn As SqlClient.SqlConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(myConnString)
    Dim comm As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM myTable", conn)
    comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Dim myTableTable As New DataTable
    conn.Open()

    myTableTable.Load(comm.ExecuteReader)
    ddl.DataSource = myTableTable.DefaultView
    ddl.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Note that I also removed the call to `PopulateDropDownList` from the Form Load Event handler.

Comment: here is an example http://www.justskins.com/forums/how-to-find-control-55963.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't why but taking the binding code from the aspx to the aspx.vb fixed the issue, so it all looks like this now:

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Parent" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlParentID" runat="server" Width="100%" >
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

And for the code-behind, for each row:

```
Dim ddl As DropDownList = CType(e.Item.Cells(3).FindControl("ddlParentID"), DropDownList)
ddl.DataValueField = "ID"
ddl.DataTextField = "Short_Description"
ddl.DataSource = myTable.DefaultView
ddl.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try to call ddlParent.DataBind() after setting the datasource.

Comment: For some reason I don't know, the ddl is not available in the code-behind. I'm new to ASP so it might be a trivial fix.

Comment: hmmm... you may start to search how to find control in ItemTemplate.

Comment: here is an example http://www.justskins.com/forums/how-to-find-control-55963.html